# How to hook save-post function to use taxonomy term in post-slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, save-post

Hook save-post function to check if taxonomy term is attached or not. If attached then, use taxonomy term in post slug like "taxonomy-term-other-words"...

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for bad representation...

Answer (score 0):

To solve your magic question(s) you might need a little chain of processes, or just do something obvious simple.

If I understand right, in the end, the current post you are saving, gonna change its slug (url) by pushing any "belonging" term name into the post url (slug)?

**Scenario A)**
If it is NOT a automated process/ batch, just edit the slug below the post title and put the words you want, then click on update post.

**Scenario B)**
Hook into `save_post` action and do a lot of stuff:

Take a first look at: [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) for:

```
wp_get_object_terms($post_id...
wp_set_object_terms($post_id...
```

In the end, the process gonna call:

```
wp_update_post(array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_name' => 'some-new-slug'
));
```

Working inside `add_action('save_post', 'do_stuff')` with `wp_update_post()` remember to remove YOUR action once you're done, to prevent the classic infinitive loop.

You also must decide which term you wanna use? category?  tag?  Product-colors? All of them and more taxonomies, might exists or related in a single post.

Well, This is a macro, shell or idea to **point you in the direction**:

```
function do_stuff($post_id){
    remove_action('save_post', 'do_stuff');
    global $post;
    $current_slug = $post->post_name;
    $categories = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'category', array('fields' => 'slug'));
    foreach(... Look at codex link above, you only might need ONE slug to merge with.

    $new_slug = $current_slug.'-'.$category_slug;

    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $new_slug
    ));

}
add_action('save_post', 'do_stuff');
```

Hope you got some flesh on the bones or Fläsk på bena, as we say in Sweden.